# NodeJS throwing error "Cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I am having a lot of problems with this. When running my Node project saved on my Desktop I get this error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module {My project name}
at Function.Module._resolveFilename
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Code in node.js using express:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
   res.send('Homepage'); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You should also share your file structure here, the error is because you will be missing or given a wrong path to a .js a file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My file has one js folder called app.js. with a simple code: var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
   res.send('Homepage'); 
});

app.listen(3000);

Comment: That's not it. Somewhere you must have something like `require('{My project name}')` Are you sure you're running the correct `.js` files?